# Why I can't read my firebase into my Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

That's my code:

```
private void readFromFirebase()
{
    try
    {
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot _anime : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Anime _a = _anime.getValue(Anime.class);
                        myAnimeList.add(_a);
                    }
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(AnimeListActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Somthing Went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And that's my log:

```
 2020-04-22 16:38:48.164 3558-3589/com.example.assignemt3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-04-22 16:38:48.164 3558-3589/com.example.assignemt3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-04-22 16:38:48.230 3558-3589/com.example.assignemt3 E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

it always shows me that there is an error in this line:

```
Anime _a = _anime.getValue(Anime.class);
```

Basically, I want to read from the firebase and my real-time database has data inside, it has an object from a class called "Anime" and I need to read this data and put it inside a list of the objects

That's my database:

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: try putting the line in a try-catch block and then find if it shows anything else. I had got a solution for such issues on using try-catch . .  .

Comment: How is `myRef` initialized? I highly recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because following the advice in there maximizes the chances that someone can help.

Comment: myRef = database.getReference("myanimes");

Comment: @MajdKayyal it should be  myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("myanimes");